# using different avro schema for new columns

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, avro, flume

I am using flume + kafka to sink the log data to hdfs. My sink data type is Avro. In avro schema (.avsc), there is 80 fields as columns.

So I created an external table like that

```
CREATE external TABLE pgar.tiz_biaws_fraud
PARTITIONED BY(partition_date INT)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/data/datapool/flume/biaws/fraud'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://xxxx-ns/data/datapool/flume/biaws/fraud.avsc')
```

Now, I need to add 25 more columns to avro schema. In that case,

if I create a new table with new schema which has 105 columns, I will have two table for one project. And if I add or remove some columns in coming days, I have to create a new table for that. I am afraid of having a lot of table which use different schema for same project.

If I swap the old schema with new schema in current table, I will have only one table for one project but I can't read and get old data anymore because of schema conflict.

What is the best way to use avro schema in case like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added new columns to avro schema like that

```
{"name":"newColumn1", "type": "string", "default": ""},
{"name":"newColumn2", "type": "string", "default": ""},
{"name":"newColumn3", "type": "string", "default": ""},
```

When I use `default` property, if that columns doesn't exist in current data it returns default value, if that columns does exist in current data it returns the data value as expected.

For setting null value as default, you need that

```
{ "name": "newColumn4", "type": [ "string", "null" ], "default": "null" },
```

or

```
{ "name": "newColumn5", "type": [ "null", "string" ]},
```

The position of null in type property, can be first place or can be second place with default property.

Comment: how to add null as default value?

Comment: would this `{ "name": "newColumn5", "type": [ "null", "string" ]}` be backward compatible as well? i have been googling and all say there has to be the `default` field to make it backward compatible.

Comment: yeah it works. If you put "string" as first argument and "null" as second argument you need to use default keyword for backward compatible. But if you set first argument as "null" in type property you do not need default declaration. @thecruisy

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed challenging. The best way is to make sure all schema changes you make are compatible with the old data - so only remove columns with defaults, and make sure you give defaults in the columns you are adding. This way you can safely swap out the schemas without a conflict and keep reading old data. Avro is pretty clever about that, it's called "schema evolution" (in case you want to google a bit more) and allows reader and writer schemas to be a bit different.

As an aside, I want to mention that Kafka has a native HDFS connector (i.e. without Flume) that uses Confluent's schema registry to handle these kinds of schema changes automatically - you can use the registry to check if the schemas are compatible, and if they are - simply write data using the new schema and the Hive table will automatically evolve to match.